# Bigquery ML in dialogflow with node.js

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, dialogflow-es

I am a noob in javascript. I don't understand the syntax of promises in dialogflow.

I am trying to make work simple BigQuery call, without success.

It returns the right info at some point in the console, but not in the flow

The example initially comes from this tutorial  "https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-dialogflow-bqml/index.html?index=..%2F..cloudai#4". I changed a bit the code as i wanted to make it work with "app.intent": `exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app)` instead of "`agent.handleRequest(intentMap)`"

I have tried to use `return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {` and `resolve`. I spent hours in stackoverflow trying several combinations of code, but none worked.

```
const ticketCollection=(conv,EMAIL,CATEGORY) => {

  // The SQL Query to Run
  const SQLQUERY = `WITH pred_table AS (SELECT 5 as seniority, "3-Advanced" as experience,
          "${CATEGORY}" as category, "Request" as type)
          SELECT cast(predicted_label as INT64) as predicted_label
          FROM ML.PREDICT(MODEL helpdesk.predict_eta,  TABLE pred_table)`;

  const OPTIONS = {
    query: SQLQUERY,
    // Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
    location: "US",
    params: {
      category: CATEGORY
    }
  };
  console.log("options",OPTIONS);
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    BIGQUERY_CLIENT.query(OPTIONS)
      .then(results => {
        //Capture results from the Query
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
        const QUERY_RESULT = results[0];
        const ETA_PREDICTION = QUERY_RESULT[0].predicted_label;
        console.log("results",QUERY_RESULT);
        console.log("eta",ETA_PREDICTION);
        resolve();
        reply(conv,`Thanks a lot, we will get back to you in ${ETA_PREDICTION} minutes`);
      });
  });
};


app.intent('Submit Ticket', (conv) => {
  console.log("Parameters", conv.parameters);
  const EMAIL = conv.parameters.email;
  const CATEGORY = conv.parameters.category;
  ticketCollection(conv,EMAIL,CATEGORY);
});
```

I want the chatbot to return the expected time. Again, I am a noob in javascript. Any suggestions or obervations would be much appreciated ! Thank you so much in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things which may be causing your problems. Without seeing all of the code, it is difficult to be sure, but here are a few problems:

**Promises and the Intent Handler**

The Intent Handler that you create with

```
app.intent('Submit Ticket', (conv) => {
```

needs to return a Promise, since you are doing asynchronous operations somewhere in there. The library needs to know when all the work has been done, the response message has been set, and it can actually return the response to the user.

Since `ticketCollection()` returns a Promise, the easiest way to do that is to just change that call to

```
return ticketCollection(conv,EMAIL,CATEGORY);
```

**Promises and resolve()**

The next issue is that you're calling `resolve()` before doing further work (calling `reply()`, whatever that is):

```
    resolve();
    reply(conv,`Thanks a lot, we will get back to you in ${ETA_PREDICTION} minutes`);
```

As mentioned above, the library assumes that everything has been done when a Promise resolves, but it looks like you're trying to set the reply *after* you call `resolve()`.

In this case, swapping the two lines will handle this. But there might be a better solution.

**Using the Promise you're provided**

That entire block of code looks pretty complicated, and can probably be simplified in a way that makes sense since `BIGQUERY_CLIENT.query(OPTIONS)` returns a Promise (as suggested by the `then()` block. So you can probably just return the Promise that it creates instead of having to wrap it in your own. (For libraries that don't return their own Promises, you may still have to wrap it, but more and more are returning Promises since its a better solution.)

So you may be able to simplify that by removing the entire `new Promise` part and the call to `resolve()` and it might look something like

```
  console.log("options",OPTIONS);
  return BIGQUERY_CLIENT.query(OPTIONS)
    .then(results => {
      //Capture results from the Query
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
      const QUERY_RESULT = results[0];
      const ETA_PREDICTION = QUERY_RESULT[0].predicted_label;
      console.log("results",QUERY_RESULT);
      console.log("eta",ETA_PREDICTION);
      reply(conv,`Thanks a lot, we will get back to you in ${ETA_PREDICTION} minutes`);
    });
```

You still need to make sure you return the Promise, and make sure it gets returned to the handler library, but that is easier code to read than trying to wrap things.

Comment: glad it helps! Note that I fixed a brain-o in the first section